# Is it possible to secure/hide ajax responses using https connection?

Tags: javascript, apache, http, https

How can we secure/hide ajax responses from being seen in debugging tools like firebug using https connection.

I have a large json data getting as a ajax response and I am using that data to build UI. But I am afraid about someone who can steal my json data and create a similar website. So I want to prevent my json data from being stolen.

Comment: How to encrypt through server side and decrypt through clientside. Was this question a irrelevant?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Nothing is safe in client side JavaScript.

Comment: then what is the way to secure those ajax response data. There must be something. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) is only a layer of security for data transmission between client and server using TLS (or SSL). That is, HTTPS cares about your data's security during the transfer. What you do with your data on either side of that isn't determined by HTTPS.

Client-side JavaScript does not have any mechanism for storing or securing that information so it is hidden from users.

Comment: Like you said https is a layer of security for data transmission between client and server using TLS (or SSL), similarly some data are transfered to server using GET or POST and thus server responds with some new data. Why these response data are not secured.?

Comment: Because an AJAX call is made from the client to get data for the user or UI in some way.  If you're not displaying this data to the user, why are you sending it to the client?

Comment: I have a json data getting as a ajax response and I am using that data to build UI. But I am afraid about someone who can steal my data and create a similar website. So I want to prevent my json data from being stolen.

Comment: Also, the data is secured going to the client, but not once it gets there.

Comment: Only traditional web applications would let you do that, like ASP.NET or a JAVA MVC.  In general, hiding code is not a big priority for a UI.

Comment: So your real need isn't to hide an AJAX response, but to secure your UI code.  Now you have something to research that actually will meet your goals.  Not to say that those goals are necessarily possible or good practice.

Comment: Then why have you given negative for this question?

Comment: I didn't give this question a negative rating as it might be useful for others.